# Nautilus start from command line

Tags: nautilus

Fresh install Ubuntu 16.04. Starting nautilus from command line produces several errors/warnings:

```
(nautilus:6169): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
(nautilus:6169): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
(nautilus:6169): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(nautilus:6169): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(nautilus:6169): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug with Nautilus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1569970).  Try re-starting Nautilus.

First, terminate the existing processes:

```
killall nautilus
nautilus -q
```

then launch it again:

```
nautilus
```

Hope this helps.